# Convert Xls to Csv for a Range of Cells

Tags: vba, excel, csv, vbscript

I have a VBA Macro to convert all .xls files present in a folder to .csv files , but there is some additional requirement to be done.

I have to select a range of columns (like from A to AQ and all the rows) and to save them into .CSV files, I tried it through Macro recording but it didn't help.

```
Sub ConvertXLStoCSVNoRules(mySourcePath)
Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set strInputFolder = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
'Set strOutputFolder = MyObject.GetFolder(myKeywordPath)
'Call DelFolder
strInputFolder = strInputFolder & "\"
MkDir (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sales")
MkDir (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Group")
strOutputFolderGroup = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Group\"
strOutputFolderSales = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sales\"
strXLSFile = Dir(strInputFolder & "*.xls*")
counter = 0
row = 24
Worksheets("Main").Cells(row, 1).Value = "Files processed at " & Now
row = row + 1
On Error Resume Next
Do While strXLSFile <> ""
counter = counter + 1
row = row + 1

If InStr(1, strXLSFile, "Sales") <> 0 Then
    'strCSVFile contains Sales Then
    'strCSVFile = Left(strXLSFile, InStrRev(strXLSFile, ".")) & "csv"
    On Error Resume Next
    strCSVFile = Left(strXLSFile, 4) & " Sales" & ".csv"

    'Add into the first sheet for recording purpose
    Worksheets("Main").Cells(row, 1).Value = strXLSFile

    Workbooks.OpenText strInputFolder & strXLSFile
    Range("A1:AQ1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strOutputFolderSales & strCSVFile, xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    strXLSFile = Dir

ElseIf InStr(1, strXLSFile, "Group") <> 0 Then

    strCSVFile = Left(strXLSFile, 4) & " Group" & ".csv"

    'Add into the first sheet for recording purpose
    Worksheets("Main").Cells(row, 1).Value = strXLSFile

    Workbooks.OpenText strInputFolder & strXLSFile
    Range("A1:AQ1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strOutputFolderSales & strCSVFile, xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    strXLSFile = Dir

Else

    Worksheets("Main").Cells(row, 1).Value = strXLSFile & " Not Processed"

End If
Loop
 'MsgBox ("Files completed " & counter)
 row = row + 1
Worksheets("Main").Cells(row, 1).Value = "Files completed " & counter & " at " & Now
End Sub
```

No error while executing code. Data does not get copied from excel files to .csv files. Excel files opened for copying are not getting closed.

Any solution would be helpful

Comments:

I have the full block of code , Now the folder containing the xls files will be segregated based on names as sales and group after converting to csv, but the converted csv files are of  1kb doesnt have any data except few junk .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently selecting is the last Row used not all the rows. You can either write
`Range("A1:AQ" & lnDyRw).select` which will select everything between A1 and AQ lnDyRw

or to Select a Range of Columns you can write:
`Range("A:AQ").select`

At the moment you should have the last line somewhere in your new workbook.